# Search a folder using ID via Google Drive API in python

Tags: python, google-drive-api

I am using the Google Drive's API to create and search files and folders using python 3. Searching a folder is done using the `files.list` method of the drive API. Each search requires a query `q` as an input. Some examples of queries are given [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files). I can successfully search for a folder named **hello** using its name as given below:

```
service.files().list(q="name = 'hello'", pageSize=10, fields=files(id, name)).execute()
```

Now, let us say the ID of the folder is **123**, then how can I search for this folder using the ID instead of the name. I have tried replacing `q` with `id = '123'` as well as `id = 123` but none of it seems to work. The closest query I was able to find [here](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files#query_string_examples) was:

```
q = "'123' in parents"
```

But this will return all the files whose parent folder is the folder we are looking for.

Is there any way in which we can directly search folders or files by their ID?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe your goal is as follows.

- You want to retrieve the folder metadata by the folder ID Drive API with googleapis for python.

In this case, how about the following sample script?

```
folderId = "###" # Please set the folder ID.
res = service.files().get(fileId=folderId, fields="id, name").execute()
```

- In this case, "Files: get" method is used.

#### Additional information:

- If you want to retrieve the folder list just under the specific folder, you can use the following modified search query.

  ```
    q = "'123' in parents and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
  ```

  - In this case, `123` is the top folder ID.
  - In this modification, the retrieved mimeType is given. By this, only the folder list can be retrieved.
- If you want to retrieve the file list except for the folder, you can also use the following search query.

  ```
    q = "'123' in parents and not mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'"
  ```
- If you want to retrieve the folder ID from the folder name, you can use the following sample script. In this case, when there are same folder names of `hello`, those folders are returned.

  ```
    res = service.files().list(q="name = 'hello' and mimeType='application/vnd.google-apps.folder'", pageSize=10, fields="files(id, name)").execute()
  ```

#### Note:

- In your showing script, please modify `fields=files(id, name)` of `service.files().list(q="name = 'hello'", pageSize=10, fields=files(id, name)).execute()` to `fields="files(id, name)"`.

#### References:

- [Files: get](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/get)
- [Search for files and folders](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/guides/search-files)

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed and helpful answer. I have one little doubt that I encountered while using the `get` method. Initially, I set the fields parameter to "files(id, name)" and received an error. But when I changed it to "id, name", I got the expected answer. What is the difference between them? The former parameter work in the `list` method.

Comment: @Birdy Thank you for replying. About your additional question of `Initially, I set the fields parameter to "files(id, name)" and received an error. But when I changed it to "id, name", I got the expected answer. What is the difference between them?`, "Files: get" returns the file metadata of one file. "Files: list" returns the file metadata of files. I think that this is the difference. If my explanation is not useful, I apologize.

Comment: it makes sense. I think that Google should have pointed out the difference in their documentation. Thanks again.